# Show $\cos^6x+\sin^6x=\frac14+\frac34 \cos^22x$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

The question is: Show that

$$\cos^6x+\sin^6x=\frac14+\frac34 \cos^22x$$

and hence, evaluate $\int^π_0(\cos^6x+\sin^6x)dx$.

For the "show" part, am I meant to expand it using the cubic role i.e. 
$x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note,

$$1=(\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x)^3 $$
$$= \cos^6x+\sin^6x+3\sin^4 x\cos^2 x +3\sin^2 x \cos^4 x$$

$$=\cos^6x+\sin^6x+3\sin^2 x\cos^2 x (\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x)$$

Thus,

$$\cos^6x+\sin^6x=1-3\sin^2 x\cos^2 x=1-\frac34(1-\cos 2x)(1+\cos 2x)$$

$$=1-\frac34(1-\cos^2 2x)=\frac14+\frac34 \cos^22x$$

Comment: Alternative ending: $2\sin x\cos x=\sin(2x)$ will give the same result

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can expand it by factoring:

$$(\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x)(\cos^4 x - \cos^2 x \sin^2 x + \sin^4 x)$$
$$=(\cos^4 x - 2 \cos^2 x \sin^2 x + \sin^4 x) + \cos^2 x \sin^2 x$$
$$=(\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x)^2 + \frac{1}{4} \sin^2 2x$$
$$=\cos^2 2x + \frac{1}{4} (1-\cos^2 2x)$$
$$=\frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{4} \cos^2 2x$$